# Why does softkeyboard continue to display in View?

Tags: android, view, android-input-method, window-soft-input-mode

I am trying to remove the code that launches the soft keyboard when an Activity loads the View.  I removed 'android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"' in the Manifest file. I then searched for any references to uses of InputMethodManager in the Activity.  There is nothing in the layout file that I can see that would trigger loading of the soft keyboard. I then cleaned project and did a rebuild of it.  The soft keyboard still loads when then View is created.   I must be missing something.  Any thoughts on why the soft keyboard would continue to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with trying to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`

if it does not work, you may need to add the following some where in your code

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextField.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Why would the default be that the keyboard loads and then I have to insert code to hide it or turn it off.  I thought the default is no soft keyboard and then you have to enable it with stateVisible or showSoftInput.

Comment: whenever a EditText get focus, the default is a keyboard will be shown.  If your have `<requestFocus/>` set, it requestFocus for you when the layout is loaded

Comment: because your default focus is going on someEditable fields ? try to `requestFocuse()` on Non Editable Fields such as `TextView`

Comment: All of the EditText fields are to accept user input.  I want to show the View first without the keyboard and then when the user clicks or touches the first EditText the code should launch the keyboard.

Comment: I know, so you should try the suggestion I made. Or you simply should not `requestFocus`

Comment: Minor problem.  The View is not matching the parent layout.  The View size is still assuming there is a keyboard being shown so the View is only using about 60% of the top-to-bottom distance of the device screen.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try this ? `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`

Comment: More information would be required, screenshots, Activity and Fragment layout, code